# Concatenate previous and latter words to a word that match a condition in R

Tags: r, regex, stringr, grepl

I need to concatenate the previous and the latter words of a condition meeting word. Specifically, those who match the condition of having a comma.

```
vector <- c("Paulsen", "Kehr,", "Diego",    "Schalper", "Sepúlveda,", "Diego")

#I know how to get which elements meet my condition:

grepl(",", vector)
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Desired output:

```
print(vector_ok)
#[1] "Paulsen Kehr, Diego", "Schalper Sepúlveda, Diego"
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `strsplit(paste(vector), "[^,] ")` gives the desired output. It splits the vector after the second space where it is not preceded by a comma.

Comment: That just makes a list with each word as a separated vector...

Comment: Look here https://stackoverflow.com/q/58560859/6461462

Comment: Excelent, thank you very much for give this a try, the answer given there seems to work for every case of my list :D

Comment: sure. I think the `regex` solution is more efficient as well. p.s. And I was very close, this would've worked: ```[^ ]+ [^ ]+, [^ ]+\\K( )```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grep()` to get the positions of the strings with a comma, expand these to a sequence +/- 1, and use this to index and then collapse the original vector.

```
idx <- grep(",", vector)
seqs <- Map(`:`, idx-1, idx+1)
sapply(seqs, function(x) paste(vector[x], collapse = " "))

[1] "Paulsen Kehr, Diego"       "Schalper Sepúlveda, Diego"
```