# Finding second space after each comma

Tags: r, regex, strsplit

<sub>This is a follow up to this question: [Concatenate previous and latter words to a word that match a condition in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58551389/concatenate-previous-and-latter-words-to-a-word-that-match-a-condition-in-r)</sub>

I am looking for a regex which splits the string at the second space that happens after comma. Look at the example below:

```r
vector <- c("Paulsen", "Kehr,", "Diego", 
            "Schalper", "Sepúlveda,", "Alejandro",
             "Von Housen", "Kush,", "Terry")

X <- paste(vector, collapse = " ")
X

## this is the string I am looking to split:
"Paulsen Kehr, Diego Schalper Sepúlveda, Diego Von Housen Kush, Terry"
```

Second space after each comma is the criterion for my [regex](/questions/tagged/regex). So, my output will be:

```r
"Paulsen Kehr, Diego"
"Schalper Sepúlveda, Alejandro"
"Von Housen Kush, Terry"
```

I came up with a pattern but it is not quite working.

```regex
[^ ]+ [^ ]+, [^ ]+( )
```

Using it with `strsplit` removes all the words instead of splitting at group-1 (i.e. `[^ ]+ [^ ]+, [^ ]+(group-1)`) only. I think I just needs to exclude the full match and match with the space afterwards only. --
[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/z383ig/17)

```r
strsplit(X, "[^ ]+ [^ ]+, [^ ]+( )")

# [1] "" [2] "" [3] "Von Housen Kush, Terry"
```

Can anyone think of a [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) for finding the ***second space after each comma***?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use

```
> strsplit(X, ",\\s+\\S+\\K\\s+", perl=TRUE)
[[1]]
[1] "Paulsen Kehr, Diego"           "Schalper Sepúlveda, Alejandro" "Von Housen Kush, Terry"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1BRzKj/1)

**Details**

- `,` - a comma
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `\S+` - 1+ non-whitespaces
- `\K` - match reset operator discarding all text matched so far
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces